# Using the free tier of getstream.io, can I have user feeds that are custom based on what pages/tags they are subscribed to?

Tags: node.js, react-native, getstream-io

I am looking for a feed API with the functionality in the question above, where a user's feed shows only the posts that match the tags the user is subscribed to. Is that possible with stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a feed for each tag, and have users follow those feeds, then their timeline will be filled with all activities from the feeds they follow. This is standard behavior in Stream Feeds.

Comment: thank you for the response! I am begging to read the docs, haha and I've cleared up a lot of fo questions. However, I just posted a new question about user creation flow in GetStream.io and firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649721/proper-user-creation-flow-with-getstream-io-and-firebase